# Regex matching file names

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have some template for file names like:

```
$subject-id$-subject-info.xml
$sampleId$-$subjectId$-sample-info.txt
$subjectId$-$sampleId$-sample-info.txt
$subjectId$-$sampleId$-image-$type$.png
$sampleId$-$subjectId$-image-$type$.jpg
image-$sampleId$-$subjectId$-$type$.jpg
```

order of `type`, `sample-id`, `subject-id` not constantly set.

I need to select files which matching this templates.

for example:

for first template maching string:

```
"123A-subject-info.xml" ($subject-id$ is string)
```

for second:

```
"2014-04-17-17-42-57-O1CD-sample-info.txt" ($sample-id$ is date time type)
```

for last:

```
"image-2014-04-17-17-42-57-01CD-mini.jpg" ($type$ is another string)
```

How  can i do it with regex ? I try to parsing this strings using split method, but i need to rewrite this method constantly if the template was changed.

Comment: so your first template is what ?, can you give some examples which you expect to match with your first template

Comment: "$subject-id$-subject-info.xml". in example subject-id = 0000

Comment: is it always going to be 4 digits ?

Comment: what language do you use?

Comment: i want to using regex tools in C#

Comment: Let me know if I'm wrong: You want to be able to get the different parts of the file name into variables: `type`, `sample-id` and `subject-id`. There will always be a subject-id in the filename, but optional sample-id and type. These variables now need to be of appropriate type, for instance if type is a date, the variable type should be of type datetime. Is there a way to distinguish between the variables? That is to say, how do you distinguish a subject-id from a sample-id? Or the other variable?

Comment: yes, subject-id is required, other - optional, depending on item type (subject or type or sample) for each item i have specific method for parsing them. for 'sample-id' - i have string in format -"yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss", for 'subject' - 4 digits or numbers, for 'type' - string with undefined length.

Comment: @al__gol Sorry, I didn't see your reply earlier. Please use @Jerry to reply to me so that I get a notification for the message :) I have another question: for example the last format; can it be `image-$sampleId$-$type$-$subjectId$.jpg`? If it can, it will be difficult because then, the `subjectID` and `type` could be mixed up...

Answer (score 1):

For example if the file is in php then it would be 
**/^\S[a-zA-Z]+.(php)$/**
But you can replace php with your preferred extension.

try using http://regex101.com/ to check your regular expression